# Which form of punctuation is correct for whereas?

Tags: punctuation

I've read in grammar books that "**whereas**" is a kind of **conjunctive adverb** and should be placed at the first of a sentence or else it have to be followed by a **semicolon**. But I've seen in many books that they just put a comma before it, so I am a little bit confused.

For instance look at the following examples:

> 1. Back in the day, people would frequently go out to meet friends, whereas today they prefer to stay at home alone, chatting online.
> 2. The number of people who use smart phones is increasing; whereas, the proportion of people go out for leisure activity is decreasing.

From grammar books, I feel like the second form is correct, but I have seen the first form of punctuation as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is certainly far more common usage than the second. It is quite rare to need punctuation both before and after a single word, and that is not one of them.

Indeed, I cannot think of any example in common, modern usage where a semi-colon would come directly after "whereas" - that word is mainly used to join two phrases, whereas a semi-colon is used to separate them.

Comment: But I am sure that I've read in every single grammar text that when you use a conjunctive adverb, put a semicolon (;) before it and a comma (,) after it!

Comment: English is not governed by "rules of grammar" it is governed by "common usage" - that is one of the reason's it is is known (over here) as "The Queen's English". Do a search on Google for "whereas", with and without a trailing comma, and see which gives more results.